# 'Exports' naming convention - how does it work?

Tags: delphi, naming-conventions, pe-exports

What rules apply to the name that ends up in the exports section of an PE (Portable Executable)?
Roughly, I see names starting with an '_' underscore, a '?' question mark or an '@' at-sign. What do those mean, and what about the rest of the name?

Also - How can I reverse the naming convention into something more usable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are refering to "dll name mangling"

[name mangling](http://cplus.about.com/gi/dynamic/offsite.htm?zi=1/XJ&sdn=cplus&cdn=compute&tm=4&gps=352_1578_1062_840&f=00&su=p284.9.336.ip_p504.1.336.ip_&tt=2&bt=1&bts=0&zu=http%3A//theory.uwinnipeg.ca/gnu/gcc/gxxint_15.html)

It's used to make sure exports names are unique

You can specify a .def file which will make it easier to use afterwards

Simply put, a .def file is just a text file containing the following structure

```
LIBRARY "MyDll"

EXPORTS
    exportFunction1
```

Comment: Note that Delphi does not use DEF files. Instead, a name can be specified in the "exports" clause within the code. An index can be specified there, too.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing : Jcl contains yet another very usefull function to decode these symbols.
You can find it in JclPeImage; It's called PeUnmangleName - which is an extension of the UndecorateSymbolNameA/W WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked a little longer before asking this - as I just found an answer to this:

It's called 'name mangling', and here's a link explaning a bit about it : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

My apologies for bothering you; Cheers!